# Is there any other way to query two databases with Oracle SQL Developer without creating a database link

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-link

I'm trying to code a query that needs to access two separate database connections and cant figure out how. I have my .sql file connected to connection: A, but i need to join information from connection: b to get all the information I need. I cant create a database link, which is the answer i'm seeing everywhere. The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.ROW_ID,
    a.ATTRIB_1,
    b.Date2
From A.user.info a, B.super.info b
Where a.stat1 = b.stat1;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing else you can do than creating that link, to go simply.

The question is why can't you?

In a company I worked for they also had a (to me: weird) politic about that, and didn't want dblinks (anymore).

They opted for [MQ queues](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/) from IBM as a substitute.

Hope it helped.